# Important DONT's for a good android app design(Beginner/Novice Level)?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider, android-activity

Can anyone point to a good source or come up with a brief listing of conceptual android programming DONT's when designing an App?

I dont want my question to be vague, so I'll give dummy examples(which might not make any sense or may be completely incorrect) to explain what kind of answers I am looking for are things like :

Eg: Avoiding these help you design/program robust android apps

1. Dont acquire wake locks when waiting for a server response OR Dont have this logic in OnReceive of a broadcast listener...
2. Extending IntentService is better than extending Services in blah blah scenario
3. Dont create threads inside OnDestroy() for activities...
   etc
   etc

I hope you got the point. I know these could be infinite do's and donts but I am looking for the most important basic ones that a beginner/novice should keep in mind so that they good be better android programmers.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

By Design I mean both the programming(logic) as well as the UI and not the look and feel alone.

Infact more importantly the ones that comes with experience and are not mentioned in books or tutorials because of the nature of these principles/tricks. They might not be absolutely right or wrong but are better or worse. Because they will not teach you a new concept but will help you get rid of a bad programming/design habit.

Comment: Now thats the kind of points I am looking for : 

Applications should avoid potentially long-running operations or calculations in BroadcastReceivers. 

You should also avoid starting an Activity from an Intent Receiver, as it will spawn a new screen that will steal focus from whatever application the user is currently has running. If your application has something to show the user in response to an Intent broadcast, it should do so using the Notification Manager.

source : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The very first most important aspect of mobile app development is the look and feel of you app. [Here](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) are Android design principles which give you killer design skills.
2. [This](http://www.slideshare.net/retomeier/being-epic-best-practices-for-building-android-apps) is an excellent resource I've found, it is written and explained by Roto Meier.
3. What would be a better teaching guide than [Android Developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html) itself
4. [This](http://www.unifiedtestinginitiative.org/files/uti_best_practices_v1_final.pdf) is a single resource which is very helpful if you are starting out
5. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384447/android-best-practices) is a same question which was asked on Stack Overflow
6. Android 4.0 enforces strict mode so check [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_strictmode/) out to know what that is
7. To design a perfect app on any platform the first basic thing you need to know is as of how to divide operations into tasks so that the app runs smoothly, multithreading is an important aspect of Mobile development, this is an excellent [link](http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-493/lecture-notes/Android-Chapter13-MultiThreading.pdf) that shows you how to make Multi-threaded Android apps
8. Ofcourse there is also a need to test you app on different devices just to make sure the UI looks perfect, and the app runs smooth. You should also make sure that your app runs on screens of different sizes.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I'll check out the links you have mentioned.